# Carabiner: cache path does not exist. Please set the cache path in config/carabiner.php

Tags: codeigniter

I am using code iginiter. When I try running my application from a local browser then this error is throwing up.

```
Carabiner: cache path does not exist. Please set the cache path in config/carabiner.php.
```

I have no clue what it is. Tried some online similar solutions  like :

```
http://www.webdevelopersdiary.com/1/archives/06-2012/1.html
```

but for some reason nothing seems to work. Please help me to come out of this.

Comment: *Did* you follow the instructions in the error message and set the cache path in `config/carabiner.php` or not? And, does the destination exist or not?

Comment: yes everything works fine..When i looked into the log file after where something called  less_css is executed and then process is aborted.... NO idea what is less_css is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create cache directory specified in `config/carabiner.php`, at line #50.

Default setting: `$config['cache_dir'] = 'assets/cache/';`

Remember that `cache_dir` path is relative to document root (aka `FCPATH` from CI ; where `index.php` is located). On initialization, `FCPATH` and `cache_dir` are concatenated, resulting `cache_path`.

Excerpt from library:
 `$this->cache_path = $this->fcpath.$this->cache_dir;`

**Update**
You need to create `assets/cache` directory, which is located in you application root, with write permissions: `mkdir -p assets/cache && chmod -R 777 assets/cache`

In the end, it will look like this:

`$ tree

.

|____application

|____assets

| |____cache

|____index.php

|____system

|____user_guide`

Comment: hi vimishor will you be bit more clear.. so that i can give a try

Comment: Hey man.. Brillian its working.... i just created a new directory assets/cache.... is there anything more to do as you mentioned  Excerpt from library:
$this->cache_path = $this->fcpath.$this->cache_dir;

Comment: I added "Excerpt from library" section, to show how "cache_path" is built inside the library. I'm glad you solved the problem. Happy coding!